# Fork vs submodule vs subtree - connected copy of a project

Tags: git, github

I have browsed through few topics but I still can't get a clear answer as to what is the best way forward for what I'm trying to do.

I have a private repository `repo_A` in my GitHub account (there is no organisation).

I would like to create a copy of repository `repo_A` and call it `repo_B`, changed few things, but still be allowed to bring new changes from `repo_A`. Things changed in `repo_B` will either be in `.gitignore` or I will decide which version to keep during merge conflicts, which is okay.

What is the best way to achieve it? Facts that I gathered so far:

- Can't fork private repo without an organisation.
- Submodule would put my original repo as a subfolder (the files have to keep its hierarchy).
- Subtree - don't quite understand the concept

Edit: I also thought that maybe completely separate repo would be a way to go and then some kind of merging of the two?

Comment: set `repo_A` as upstream of `repo_B`?

Comment: Does it mean that `repo_B` would send changes to `repo_A`? Because I only want it to work the other way. `repo_B` is for alike a demo version rather than development

Comment: You might not be able to fork it within github but that doesn't stop you from forking on your local machine. You would just set your origin as `repo_B` and develop normally and add another remote to only _fetch_ changes from `repo_A` which you could then merge to your branches then push back into `repo_B`.

Comment: That sounds like it could work, thank you @JeffMercado. Could you just help me with the right commands? I'm not sure where to start. Would I just copy the files from `repo_A` to `repo_B` and push it to remote?

Comment: I tried adding new remote but when doing `git pull ups_origin master` I get an error `fatal:  refusing to merge unrelated histories`